# Beautiful soup returns empty list on one website, but works on another website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently learning Python through "Automate the boring stuff with Python".
I'm doing the Web Scraping part at the moment.

I wrote code that gets that price of a product from one website. However, when I edit my code a little to work on another website is does not seem to work, and Beautiful Soup returns an empty list from the CSS.

This is my working code.

```
import bs4, requests, re

def getPrice(productUrl):
    res = requests.get(productUrl)
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

    # Go through CSS and get price
    source = soup.select('#product_addtocart_form > div.product-shop > div.details-info')
    element = source[0].text.strip()
    # Regex for getting the price from the rest of the CSS.
    pattern = re.compile(r"""R([1-9]\d*)(\.\d\d)?(?![\d.])""")

    # Get price from string using regex pattern
    trueprice = re.split(pattern, element)
    return("The product's price is : R " + trueprice[1])

product = "https://www.faithful-to-nature.co.za/green-home-paper-straws-in-compostable-bag"

weblink = getPrice(product)

print(weblink)
```

This is my edited code for another website that does not work.
I commented some code out because it serves no function while there is no data in the list.

```
import bs4, requests, re

def getPrice(productUrl):
    res = requests.get(productUrl)
    res.raise_for_status() # Check for any errors in request

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

    # Go through CSS and get price
    csssource = soup.select('#shopfront-app > div > div.grid-container.pdp-grid-container > div.grid-x.grid-margin-x > div > div > div > div > div.cell.medium-auto > div.pdp-core-module_actions_mdYzm > div.sf-buybox.pdp-core-module_buybox_q5wLs.buybox-module_buybox_eWK2S')
    #element = csssource[0].text.strip()

    # Regex for getting the price from the rest of the CSS.
    pattern = re.compile(r"""R([1-9]\d*)(\.\d\d)?(?![\d.])""")

    #trueprice = re.split(pattern, element)
    #return("The product's price is : R " + trueprice[1])

    print(csssource)

test1 = "https://www.takealot.com/lego-classic-basic-brick-set-11002/PLID53430493"


weblink = getPrice(test1)

print(weblink)
```

With both sites I got the CSS-selector using the inspect method on Chrome. I tried using wider CSS-selectors but Beautiful Soup still returns an empty list.

How do I get Beautiful Soup to return the correct list / CSS-selector?

Comment: Do you want a solution only with css selection or will another way do?

Comment: @Rakshith-Gb I've only so far learned about the CSS selection, but if there is a better way I would gladly like to learn about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I believe this site is serving dynamic content, so you will need to employ selenium, when I try to scrape with just requests / bs i get blank lists also. You can probably use your original css selection critera, but i selected for the 5th occurance of currency for the price your trying to get.

Download the correct gecko driver and set the path in the script.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

#self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'D:\Selenium_RiponAlWasim\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.takealot.com/lego-classic-basic-brick-set-11002/PLID53430493')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
i = 0
for span in soup.find_all('span',{'class' : 'currency'}):
    if(i == 4):
        print(span.text)
    i += 1
#driver.close()
#returns R 315
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the requests that are happening in a browser, you'll notice that the site is getting its product details via JSON from a call to https://api.takealot.com/rest/v-1-8-0/product-details/{PRODUCT_ID}?platform=desktop (e.g. https://api.takealot.com/rest/v-1-8-0/product-details/PLID53430493?platform=desktop).

So another option with this site rather than using selenium is to call the API yourself.

```
import requests

def getProductInfo(productId):
    productUrl = 'https://api.takealot.com/rest/v-1-8-0/product-details/{0}?platform=desktop'.format(productId)
    res = requests.get(productUrl, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)'})
    res.raise_for_status() # Check for any errors in request
    return res.json()

product = getProductInfo("PLID53430493")
print(product['buybox']['pretty_price'])
```

Comment: I'm relatively new to all of this. How did you discover the  https://api.takealot.com/rest/v-1-8-0/product-details/PLID53430493?platform=desktop) link? How do I get other products information like that?